# zLib with Qt C++ MCCP/ Telnet Compress2 option

Tags: c++, qt, telnet, zlib

I am attempting to compress/decompress QStrings.

How I have this setup: There is a telnet/socket module that reads information from a telnet server. Those strings are then sent to Javascript(It's a think client where the UI is implemented in HTML using QWebView etc.). This is working fine.

I would like to add in support for MCCP ( zlib compression of input/output).

I would like, if at all possible, to allow full scripting support for the app (Only minimal C++ code, everything else is implemented by plugins.)

I want to implement two functions, compressString and decompressString:

```
QString MainWindow::compressString(QString s) {

    QByteArray str = s.toLocal8Bit();

    int ret,flush;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    ret = deflateInit(&strm,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    if ( ret != Z_OK ) {
        return "ERROR: Failed to init z_stream";
    }
    // do until end of string
    do {
       strm.avail_in = str.size();
       strm.next_in = (unsigned char*)str.data();
       strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
       strm.next_out = out;
       flush = Z_FINISH;
       ret = deflate(&strm,flush);
       if ( ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR) {
           return "ERROR: Z_STREAM_ERROR when deflating.";
       }
    } while ( flush != Z_FINISH );
    deflateEnd(&strm);
    return QString( (char *)out );
}
QString MainWindow::decompressString(QString s) {
    QByteArray str = s.toLocal8Bit();

    int ret,flush;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit(&strm);
    if ( ret != Z_OK ) {
        return "ERROR: Failed to init z_stream for inflate";
    }
    // do until end of string
    do {
       strm.avail_in = str.size();
       strm.next_in = (unsigned char*)str.data();
       strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
       strm.next_out = out;
       flush = Z_NO_FLUSH;
       ret = inflate(&strm,flush);
       if ( ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR) {
           return "ERROR: Z_STREAM_ERROR when inflating.";
       }
       switch( ret ) {
        case Z_NEED_DICT:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_NEED_DICT";
           break;
        case Z_DATA_ERROR:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_DATA_ERROR";
           break;
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_MEM_ERROR";
           break;
        default:
           break;
       }
    } while ( ret != Z_STREAM_END );
    inflateEnd(&strm);

    return QString( (char *)out );
}
```

This is about the 3rd/4th rewrite I have tried. The compress string method returns this: xóHÍÉÉWÏ/ÊIQ
Maybe it's correct, maybe not, don't know.

The decompressString method returns this: Error: Z_NEED_DICT;

No matter what I do (I've tried some other examples found on the web, and on stack overflow).

Right now I am just feeding in strings from JS, eventually I would like to actually compress/decompress strings sent from a telnet server using the telopt 86.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.  My goal right now is just to rig up a simple in/out test.

UPDATE:

After going through the zlib inflate code, my issue is here:

```
state->mode = hold & 0x200 ? DICTID : TYPE;
```

Zlib is expecting some  kind of header on the string. `hold` is the buffer, and DICTID will send it to request Z_DICT_NEEDED. This is most likely because the header isn't there, or gets lost while the string is passing around. If I hack it and say `state->mode = TYPE;` then I will get a data error.

In addition, I changed the decompress function like this:

```
QString MainWindow::decompressString(QString s) {
    QByteArray str = s.toLocal8Bit();

    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    for ( int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ ) {
        in[i] = (unsigned char)str.at(i);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    int ret,flush;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit(&strm);
    if ( ret != Z_OK ) {
        return "ERROR: Failed to init z_stream for inflate";
    }
    // do until end of string
    do {
       strm.avail_in = str.size();
       strm.next_in = in;
       strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
       strm.next_out = out;
       flush = Z_NO_FLUSH;
       ret = inflate(&strm,flush);
       if ( ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR) {
           return "ERROR: Z_STREAM_ERROR when inflating.";
       }
       switch( ret ) {
        case Z_NEED_DICT:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_NEED_DICT";
           break;
        case Z_DATA_ERROR:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_DATA_ERROR";
           break;
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
           inflateEnd(&strm);
           return "Error: Z_MEM_ERROR";
           break;
        default:
           break;
       }
    } while ( ret != Z_STREAM_END );
    inflateEnd(&strm);

    return QString( (char *)out );
}
```

Then using printf on both the output produced by deflate, and then what's being sent to inflate and the data (hex values for each char) seem to be the same.

Comment: It seems that inspecting the out buffer shows that there are something like 4 bytes of data after the null in what is produced by deflate.

I may have to implement this as a QObject with a toString method so that I can maintain a byte buffer that I can pass around? No idea how to do this with just QStrings.

Comment: In your `(de)compressed` functions you are using the `out` and `in` buffers in a loop without advancing it. This will overwrite any previous data if the loop iterates more than one time. Maybe it does for the compress-function and thus you lose the dictionary.

Comment: That shouldn't affect the in, which is where the dict would be anyway no? The buffer is so big, and the string so small, it shouldn't loop...CHUNK is HUGE, like 16 kilobytes.

Comment: My plan was to allow the JS Layer/Plugins to choose to do MCCP, but maybe I will just put it in the C layer and unzip the QByteArray contents when it comes over the wire. It may just be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you can't.

QStrings "lose" some of the data. In order to do compression/decompression with zlib you need to work with QByteArray, in fact, it's even easier if your work with just STL strings, and only convert to QByteArrays when you need to. The solution I found that works is one from pantehma.net http://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html

Because I am reading compressed strings from an exterior source, I just don't convert them to QStrings and handle the Compression/decompression in the C layer, and don't bother passing it up to the javascript. It just wasn't worth the effort to get it to work.

Merry Christmas to the person who voted down the question.